# jquery mobile input fields in single line

Tags: jquery-mobile

How Do I align the Jquery input fields in single horizontal line ?

```
 <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <legend>Term:</legend>
            <label for="txtSDate">
            </label>
            <input id="txtSDate" name="txtSDate" value="<%=sdate%>" placeholder="Enter start date" type="date"  data-inline="true"
                maxlength="12" />
            <label for="txtEDate">
            </label>
            <input id="txtEDate" name="txtEDate" value="<%=edate%>" type="date" maxlength="12" placeholder="Enter end date" />
        </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: Use grids http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.2/dist/demos/widgets/grids/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you missed the fieldcontian?
please try below:

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
   <label for="txtSDate"></label>
   <input id="txtSDate" name="txtSDate" value="<%=sdate%>" placeholder="Enter start date"  type="date"  data-inline="true" maxlength="12" />
</div>
```